# Eclipse: search for folders and resources in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a way to search easly anything which is shown Project Explorer.
Using Open Resource dialog allows me only to search for resources.
I found this question [How to find Eclipse projects & folders by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786563/how-to-find-eclipse-projects-folders-by-name) but the plugins described there looks like do not work in Eclipse Juno properly.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549234/search-for-folder-name-using-eclipse-search-in-file

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly it, but better than nothing:

Expand everything you want to search (try using shift+numpad *).
Once it's actually visible, you can start typing keyword, and it will be located.

Plugins like eclipse glance allow for highlighting, moving, wildcards, regular expressions.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, which allows you to locate resource(s) directly, without even browsing through project explorer.

Answer (score 0):

With [Eclipse 4.14](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/) (part of the [Eclipse 2019-12](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipseide/2019-12/) simultaneous release, available December 18, 2019), you can use **Find Actions**

See "[Find Actions lists workspace files](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/platform.php#open-file-find-actions)"

> Find Actions can now list matching file names from the workspace (similar to the Open Resource dialog). Upon selection the file is opened in the editor.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/images/find-actions-resources.png]

Note: the name "Find Actions" (and Quick Access) are debated in [issue 547755](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547755#c82).